# How to stop direct access...?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a game for class and as with most games the user moves on to the next level when they complete the first level. I have used this under the `If` statement in my `game.php` file to check when the user has won.

```
if (passOnLevel == 0 && passengerCarrying == 0) {
    alert("You Win!");
    var levelOneC = '46A_gsnvh6dhABS';
    window.location.href="gameL2.php?auth=" + levelOneC;
}
```

In my `gameL2.php` file I use this at the top of my page:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["auth"])) {
    $levelOneC = $_GET["auth"];
} else {
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=customise.php">';    
  exit;    
}
?>
```

My issue is that someone can access level two even if they haven't played level one. Is there a way I can fix this or randomly generate keys to authenticate access to the next level?

Comment: I would recommend you to use sessions instead. Your top js can easily be found and I can just put ameL2.php?auth=46A_gsnvh6dhABS to go to level 2

Comment: You can't protect code at the client. If you want something to happen securely, you have to do it on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, you could use `sessions` to see if they have permission to be at level 2 or above.

So, maybe something like `if ($_SESSION['level'] >= current_level)`. If that's true, then they are good (who cares if they went back to an earlier level?). If false, then redirect them to level 1.

[Here's a quick tutorial I found to get you started if you don't know about sessions.](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Comment: Oh, yeah. I have sessions for a lot of my settings variables. I never thought of doing it like that.